# Any difference in declaring useState in these two different ways?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and am wondering is there any difference between using:

```
  const [guessedLetters, setGuessedLetters] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

and

```
  const [guessedLetters, setGuessedLetters] = useState([] as string[]);
```

Answer (score 3):

They produce identical types.

To support my claim and give you more confidence, here's the type for the `useState` overload signature that accepts an argument (from [the latest commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ef99180a81bea833ccb9e80631636fa4a959f17c/types/react/index.d.ts#L892-L898) at the time I write this message):

```ts
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

So, whether you supply a type for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter or use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on the argument value, the outcome is the same in this case.

Here's a reproduction of your example in the TypeScript playground, showing the inferred types of the destructured tuple values:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlGBDGaC+cAZlBCHAORRrYDGMFA3AFDO0QB2K8A2s3HG640ARgA0zAPSSAegH5+gtDCzDxU2QoC6cALxxUmHHgA83KMA4BzHloB8AClsBKFm07c4fAULwAmCWl5RXQVYzQAjWCdfUNVPCcdbBRBGAtrF0YgA)

```ts
import {useState} from 'react';

const [
  state1,
//^? const state1: string[]
  setState1,
//^? const setState1: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>
] = useState<string[]>([]);

const [
  state2,
//^? const state2: string[]
  setState2,
//^? const setState2: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>
] = useState([] as string[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the compiler is concerned: No

But to a reader of the code:

1. The first example is preferable for readability - it's more concise
2. Additionally, you should try to limit the uses of type assertions until:

   - ["you will have information about the type of a value that TypeScript can’t"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#:%7E:text=Sometimes%20you%20will%20have%20information%20about%20the%20type%20of%20a%20value%20that%20TypeScript%20can%E2%80%99t%20know%20about.) (Docs)

```js
const [guessedLetters, setGuessedLetters] = useState<string[]>([]);
```